# Swiftstack web console is not comming up

Tags: openstack-swift

I have created swiftstack cluster using swiftstack guidelines. Everything went perfect. i got a web console link after "Job Finished Config Deploy finished successfully." But, I am not able to get the web console, getting "This webpage is not available". Is this because of firewall or any configuration issue?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should email support@swiftstack.com directly for these issues, this forum isn't frequented by our support team.

My hunch is that you need to change from using the SwiftStack Load Balancer to No Load Balancer on the cluster configuration page, and redeploy.  Please follow up any inquiries at the email above.

Comment: Thanks Tennis!  I redeployed with the option you suggested, it didn't work but i'll connect to support@swiftstack.com